# Table columns contraints tree strcuture

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am working on a data migration project and during the data generation for target tables i need to make sure that each record respect the constraints of the table.

I need to perform a tree structure of constraints that will start from my target table to reach the last table that needs to contain reliable data to allow data to be loaded successfully into migration target **Table A**.

As an Example:

```
[Target Table A] Structure(
Column_1,
Column_2, -- constraint linked to [Foreign column on Table B]
COlumn_3, -- constraint linked to [Foreign column on Table C]
)

[Table B] Structure(
Column_11,
Column_12, -- constraint linked to [Foreign column on Table D]
COlumn_13,
)

[Table C] Structure(
Column_21,
Column_22,
COlumn_23,
)

[Table D] Structure(
Column_31,
Column_32,
COlumn_33,
)

Here i will need to perform an analyze on target Table A and the result must be like:

>Table A =>
          Contains 2 constraints on 2 tables that need data:
         -Table B =>
                    Constraint 1 contraint on 1 table:
                    -Table D
         -Table C
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question with a [MRE] including: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; and the expected output for that sample data. Your text description does not tell us how you expect the output to be displayed. For example, do you want columns in a SQL statement or are you expecting us to use `DBMS_OUTPUT` in PL/SQL, which is what you have tagged?

Answer (score 0):

Start with this

```
SELECT LEVEL, fk.table_name, fk.constraint_name, fk.r_constraint_name, pk.table_name as target_table
FROM user_constraints fk
    JOIN user_constraints pk ON fk.r_constraint_name = pk.constraint_name
START WITH fk.constraint_type = 'R'
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR fk.r_constraint_name = fk.constraint_name
;
```